# Any ideas about where this exception might have come from?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm running an app on GAE/J and getting a MemcacheServiceException.  I never explicitly use Memcache myself, so I'm assuming this has something to do with appstats or some hidden service I don't understand well - but I'm frustrated with no way to tell where the problem is happening. No part of the stack trace is in my code.

Since the requests are only taking 2 seconds to fail (20 cpu seconds!) I don't think I'm running into a deadline issue.

Below is the full error message:

```
12-11 06:18PM 04.668 /teacherview/ass 500 1863ms 19030cpu_ms 16767api_cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.215 Safari/534.10,gzip(gfe)
206.53.64.7 - - [11/Dec/2010:18:18:06 -0800] "POST /teacherview/ass HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.215 Safari/534.10,gzip(gfe)" - ms=1864 cpu_ms=19031 api_cpu_ms=16768 cpm_usd=0.529139
W 12-11 06:18PM 06.526
/teacherview/ass
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache put: Set failed to set 1 keys: [B@1976073
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:481)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:491)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:235)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:160)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:150)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:261)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8495)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8493)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:435)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:572)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
C 12-11 06:18PM 06.528
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache put: Set failed to set 1 keys: [B@1976073
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:481)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:491)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:235)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:160)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:150)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:261)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8495)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8493)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:435)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:572)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug, reported just four days ago:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/bb363b18aaa7d68b/a40a7e63ad8311f5